# How to use postgresql variable in where clause

Tags: postgresql

```sql
-- It works! 
select * from device where device.user_id in (select user_id from user);

-- It doesn't work! 
select user_id into test from user;
select * from device where device.user_id in test;
```

Why does the first one work but second?

If I want to use a variable in `where` clause like the above, how can I do that?

Comment: `(select user_id from user)` gives you a whole result set, not a single value. Do you see why the second method won't do the same as the 1st?

Comment: You could do this with `DO` block but DO block does not output select. So you need to use function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually `select user_id from user` will result in an error, because `user` is a reserved keyword (function) that returns the current user - and that does not have a column named `user_id`. See here: https://rextester.com/EPWT79333

The reason why it works in the sub-select of the first query, is that any column not available in the tables of the sub-query will resolve to a column from the outer query.

So the query:

```
select * 
from device 
where device.user_id in (select user_id from user);
```

Is actually the same as:

```
select * 
from device 
where device.user_id = user_id;
```

If you do have a table named `user` you have to quote it, to make clear that you mean the table, not the built-in function: `"user"`

So the correct form for the first query is:

```
select * 
from device 
where device.user_id in (select user_id from "user");
```